# Install and run Mac Python Open CV

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I have python installed, python 3 installed, installed opencv using homebrew, also installed python through the GUI, followed various instructions pages and comments written several years ago.

I'd like to use OpenCV to detect brightest and darkest pixels and draw line between them to carve the image up into cells based on the bright and dark points in each cell. I assume this a reasonable application for this software.

When I go to python, any installation, and enter import cv I get a 'no module' message.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to decide whether you want to run Python2 or Python 3. I would advocate Python 3, firstly because this is clearly a new project so you may as well use the latest and greatest Python, and secondly since Python 2 is end-of-lifed in 9 days' time.

Then you need to decide if you want to use the Apple-supplied Python, in `/usr/bin` or the **homebrew** supplied Python. As you have installed **homebrew** Python, I would advocate using the **homebrew** one because you can delete the whole thing and re-install it if you mess it up while all the Apple-supplied patches, OS upgrades and their other uses of their Python will remain unaffected. Happy days!

So, you want to use **homebrew** Python 3. Now check what **homebrew** tells you, by running:

```
brew info python
```

> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
>   `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been
>   installed into   /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

That means if you want to run `python` and `pip` (without a version number, as opposed to `python3` and `pip3`) and expect that to start Python 3 and its corresponding `pip`, you need to put `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` at the start of your PATH in your `bash profile` (probably `$HOME/.bash_profile`):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH
```

Then start a new Terminal and check which Python runs when you type `python`:

```
type python
```

And it must report as follows if you are on the right track:

```
python is /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
```

Then, you can check which Python version that is with:

```
python -V
```

and it should be:

```
Python 3.7.5
```

Now you can install OpenCV with:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Then load it in the interpreter with:

```
import cv2
```

---

If, for some reason, you want to run the old v2.7 Python, or risk messing up the installation of your **macOS** by installing clashing modules, just disregard my answer.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. I'd suggest opening a new question about the image processing now that your environment is all set up. Add input images and expected result images to your question.