# MacOS Catalina, pip has installed packages but python cannot find them?

Tags: python, macos, pip, zsh, macos-catalina

My pip has worked fine with my python 3 in the past and I have downloaded things such as pandas which all work fine in python. The problem I now encounter is any library I attempt to download using pip is not recognised by python. Here is how I have tried downloading skl.

```
pip install sklearn
pip3 install sklearn
```

When I input

```
pip list
```

or

```
pip3 list
```

Both list sklearn as being downloaded, however, when I go in python and input:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nicross/Desktop/RainDance/RainFaller.py",line 8, in <module>
    from sklearn import linear_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From Python3.4 my preferred way of installing packages using pip is to run `python -m pip install sklearn`. This way you can be sure that the `pip` command you are using is for the correct interpreter

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: Run `which python` and `which pip` to see which installations of python and pip you’re running. If there’s a discrepancy, one will not see packages installed by the other.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447268/2836621

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks, I ran python3 -m pip install sklearn and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python3 -m pip install sklearn
```

Answer (score 0):

From the sklearn docs it looks like you might want to try:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

(For more, try following the steps here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html and see if those fix it)