# How do I use downloaded Python packages in macOS?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm on macOS using Visual Studio Code and I can't import a module downloaded with pip. If I run in terminal `which -a pip` it gives `/usr/local/bin/pip`, if I run `which -a python` it gives `/usr/bin/python`. Also if I run `pip list`, it displays all my modules but in the python file it says `no module named...`. I know that there is a python 2.7 from apple and also my python 3.6.1, maybe they are conflicting? I tried installing pip using `sudo /usr/bin/python get-pip.py` but nothing changes. What can I do? Maybe there's a way of installing python that I don't know?

Edit: I tried the method in the comment for python and homebrew (I already had homebrew installed) but python 3.7.6 is not seen by Visual Studio Code, instead it sees python 3.8.1 (not installed), python 3.7.3 (the one included in XCode?) and python 2.7 (the one from apple). So now my problem is that Visual Studio Code doesn't see the correct python version...

Edit2: I'm using catalina

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/pip` sounds like a `pip` you installed yourself, while `/usr/bin/python` sounds like macOS' builtin Python. The two have nothing to do with one another. There's probably also a `python*` somewhere in `/usr/local/bin` which corresponds to that `pip`.

Comment: Do you get ``/usr/local/bin/python`` on running ``which -a python3``?

Comment: If you are using **homebrew** for Python, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447268/2836621

Comment: if I type "which -a python3" it gets "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3"

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**

- Always install python without SUDO. It messes up the package.
- Also check out Homebrew for installing codes in MacOS, Its is very useful. link : https://brew.sh/

Open Terminal from your launchpad.

Then type in

```
python
```

If it opens interpreter, then python is already installed in your OS due to default requirement. Else install it.

**To Install:**

```
python -m pip install <Your-Package-Name-Here>
```

- Example

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

Comment: doing "/usr/bin/python get-pip.py" without sudo gives errors...