# Running python in Terminal brings up the wrong version

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

When running `python` in my terminal, it runs Python 3.6 even though my latest python version is 3.8. My `~/.bash_profile` has `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH` and my `~/.bashrc` has `alias python='/usr/bin/python3.8'`

Any way I can make it open Python 3.8 when running `python` in the terminal?

I am not too familiar with Mac and I have tried other questions but couldn't solve it.

Comment: What does `which python` report?

Comment: What is the output of `type python`?

Comment: It is not a mac issue. It is your shell. Are you using BASH?

Comment: @DYZ `/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: @Brian `python is hashed (/usr/local/bin/python)`

Comment: @AnthonyKong bash

Comment: @smor Bash has cached the path to the executable associated with `python`. To force it to re-lookup `python` on your `PATH`, manually [clear the hash cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

Comment: @Brian still runs Python 3.6

Comment: I think that my path is messed up because when I go to `/usr/local/bin/python` which is my `which python` there is no Python 3.8.

Comment: I explained it very clearly here, please have a read... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447268/2836621

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you should do is :

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: No, you definitely should not do that! It is generally considered poor practice to make changes in `/usr/bin`. That directory is managed by your OS-vendor and operating system upgrades both depend on those programs being specific versions and also reserve the right to change them themselves. You should make symlinks and changes in `/usr/LOCAL/bin` or elsewhere but never in `/usr/bin`. It is asking for trouble.