# I installed requests but still got import requests ImportError: No module named requests python

Tags: python-3.x, macos, web-scraping, visual-studio-code, python-requests

I'm following this tutorial for web scraping and tried to run it as test initially but always get this error message on VS Code even though I've installed the latest Python version 3.8.1 along with requests module, this's the error message below
[image]
This's the tutorial link and you can pause at 5:07 to see him running and testing the code normally without any errors.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY&t=241s

And this's my code so far running on Mac OS

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup





URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/-/de/dp/B07RF1XD36/ref=lp_16225007011_1_6?s=computers-intl-ship&ie=UTF8&qid=1581249551&sr=1-6'


headers ={"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}


page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())

print('Hello')
```

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447268/2836621

Comment: try `python -m pip install requests`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell tried what you explained but still got Python 2.7.16!!

Comment: @saurabhbaid I've already tried that before and it still doesn't work!

Comment: Ok, so which Python do you want to use - Apple's v2.7, Apple's Python3, or Homebrew? What command do you use to start Python? And what command do you use to start `pip`? Please update your question - do not reply in the comments area.

Comment: As you see in the question, I've installed Python version 3.8.1 which means I want Python3 and it's shown below in VS Code that I'm running Python version 3.8.1 64bit but I don't why I still get python 2.7.16 when I run python --version on the terminal and I don't why import requests is not functioning normally. Note: that I've tried what explained before along with tutorials to install Python3 and upgrade python from 2 to 3 on Mac Os and it seems doesnt work.

Comment: If you run `type python` like I said in the answer I linked to, you will see why you get version 2.7.

Comment: If you run `/usr/bin/python -V` you will see that that is Apple's old python v2.7

Comment: if you have both Python 2 and 3 installed you can use `python3` to get v3.x, and use `python3 -m pip install requests`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I get python is hashed (/usr/bin/python) when I run type python, and I get Python 2.7.16 when I run /usr/bin/python -V

Comment: I tried this python3 -m pip install requests before but still doesnt work! How can I delete python 2 and make python 3 default for my mac?

Comment: Exactly! If you want to run **Homebrew** Python v3.8, when you type `python` you have to read the answer I linked to that tells you to do `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH`

Comment: You must not delete Python2 - it is part of the OS that Apple supplies and Apple expects to be there when installing and running other packages. You simply install Python from **homebrew** and make sure that when you type `python` or `python3` you are using the **homebrew** one by setting your PATH correctly. You must also ensure that the `pip` you use will install its packages in the same `python` you use... which is what @rioV8 is telling you as well.

Comment: Thank you all, I figured it out, All I did based on another answer is writing and adding python3 fileName.py instead of python