# why do mac os need to install python with brew while there is default python and how to use it with pipenv?

Tags: python, homebrew, pipenv

While setting up my mac os for python development, I found it was very annoying thing to handle python correctly. I read tons of tutorial related python installation but no one clearly explain why I should do and how system really works. 
Every tutorial says use `homebrew` to install `python`. So I did and use `alias` to make `python` command pointing to the one that is installed by `homebrew`. But if I use this setting with `pipenv`, `python` after `pipenv shell` keep failing to use proper python. I think it's because even in `pipenv` environment `python` keeps pointing to python from homebrew due to `alias`. Is it right? To wrap all these up, here are three main questions.

1. why do we need to use `homebrew install python` while there is python as default? ( It makes harder to manage python)
2. How can I always use python that is installed through `homebrew` and ignore the default python
3. In above case of `pipenv`, am I right? is it because `alias`? If it is, how can I use `homebrew` with `pipenv`? (which means that without `pipenv`, using python installed by `homebrew` and after `pipenv shell` use python made by `pipenv`.

Comment: Apple only started shipping Python 3.x relatively recently. Before that, you only got Apple's ancient v2.7, so folks tended to use **homebrew** to get something current. One reason to use **homebrew** Python is that you can easily wipe it out and start again if you make a mess - reinstalling Apple's Python is not really possible.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for clear explanation. Do you know how to set python installed by homebrew to default and not use any of default mac Python? (I tried alias but if I use this, it makes conflict with pipenv.

Comment: Avoid aliases - they just confuse everyone and aren't always activated (when you run under cron, for example, or as a different user). The secret is to set your PATH correctly and use a shebang... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447268/2836621

Comment: You could use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), to **change the global Python version**