# How can I start over with a fresh install of Python on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, kivy, python-3.8

When I started learning Python I didn't understand the importance of virtual environments and I installed loads of packages globally. When I updated my Mac it also installed Python 3.8, so now I have that along with 3.7 and its packages.

Largely because it's messy and takes up space, and also to help me have a better handle on how Python is working on my computer, I want to remove the old version and its associated packages and simply have Python 3.8 as it comes with my OS. What can I safely remove without interfering with Python 3.8?

EDIT: Removed previous information that wasn't as relevant to this question.

Comment: just make a virtual environment? `python3 -m venv ./my_kivy_env` or use whatever version of Python you want, `python3.8 -m venv ./my_venv` you get the idea...

Comment: Ok. Just tried it. Inside the virtual environment, using both `python3.8 -m pip install kivy` and `pip install kivy` produced the same lengthy error message. I'm not sure which parts of this error message are relevant to post.

Comment: make a virtual environment and then install the virtual environment. you _should not_ be installing any packages in your base installation. but feel free to post either error message.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't recognize the importance of venv when I first started, which is why I want to clear out the packages, etc. that I've installed and start fresh. 

I edited my post with a truncated version of the error.

Comment: I think I essentially have two questions: 1. How do I remove previously installed versions of Python and its packages in a way that doesn't mess up the version that comes with the macOS? And 2. Why can't I install Kivy in this situation?

I'm going to edit the question to reflect the first, and create a new question for the second.

Comment: your error message is unrelated to pip. it would seem your machine does not have the appropriate files needed in order to compile kivy.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447268/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell, that really helps this make sense. I'm guessing I have a homebrew Python3.7 and an Apple-supplied Python3.8. I'll try to use homebrew to uninstall Python3.7 and delete any packages along with it. Then either reinstall or just use the Apple-supplied Python. Worst case scenario, I can reinstall Python through either of those, right?

Comment: My personal preference is to leave all the Apple-supplied stuff pristine and untouched. I install all packages I want via **homebrew** and can delete, re-install, add and remove to my heart's content without upsetting anything.

Comment: I see that some commenters have already brought up venv, so I thought I would mention my tool of choice; Conda. I'm also on macOS, it's been good so far.

Comment: I'll look into Conda as well.

Can I move the whole `usr/local/` folder into the trash? I don't have any python projects (or any other language) that I need to keep, so the only ramifications are that I would have to reinstall all the packages that I need to use (like Homebrew and git), right? I just don't want to remove anything that messes up my computer outside of working with Python.