# What's the difference between these three "python" in Mac OS X preinstalled python2.7?

Tags: python, macos, bin

I know that Mac OS X has preinstalled a python version of 2.7.
It's located in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/.
In this directory, I found 3 different python as below:

1. /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/python(which is a unix excecutable file. I double-clicked it. Then it popped out a terminal windows and said process ended. I couldn't type anything in that popped out windows.)
2. /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7(I'm not sure what filetype it is. And I found that 'which python'(/usr/bin/python) symlinked to it.)
3. /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python(which is an application. However if I double-click it, it will do nothing. I choosed to reveal this package and found there was another python in it(Contents/MacOS/Python). I double-clicked it and it popped out a terminal in which I can type in python2 script and get result interactively. )

So as a Newbie to python, I want to know what is the usage of these three "python" (and what's the difference)? When I type python in terminal, which "python" will I actually awake?

And if it's OK, I want to know what do all the directories do in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/.
Here is the list:

bin
Extras
include
lib
Mac
Python
Resouces

Comment: Python 2 is finished and has been since the start of this year. If, as it seems, you are just getting started, I would suggest you use Python 3.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for your advice, Mark. But the same confusion exists in python 3. So it's not about the version. It's about the meanings of these python directories. I recently want to manage the environment of multi-version python. So I really want to know what does each file/directory exactly do. It might lead to a deeper understanding of python.

Comment: My thoughts are embodied here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447268/283662 Other people have other ideas. I'm no great Python expert but have installed many many Python packages that way to answer StackOverflow questions on many topics and have never had a single issue with incompatibility or clashes. I don't use `venvs` at all, by the way.