# How to update python3 on Mac homebrew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I am running python3 next to python on my mac (10.15.4). To be honest I don't exactly know how I installed that years ago. My guess is homebrew. Now I want to update to the newest version. How do I do that?

```
user@192-143-0-9 ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.16
user@192-143-0-9 ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.7.1
user@192-143-0-9 ~ % brew update
error: gc died of signal 9
Fast-forwarded master to origin/master.
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
```

As of this posting python3 is on version 3.8.2 which is where I want to upgrade to. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447268/2836621

Answer (score 7):

This solved it for me:

```
% brew upgrade python3
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
phpunit

==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
python3 3.7.1 -> 3.7.7
...
% python3 -V
Python 3.7.7
```